# How to use regex to tell if first and last character of a string match?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm relatively new to using Python and Regex, and I wanted to check if strings first and last characters are the same.

If first and last characters are same, then return 'True' (Ex: 'aba')
If first and last characters are not same, then return 'False' (Ex: 'ab')

Below is the code, I've written:

```
import re
string = 'aba'
pattern = re.compile(r'^/w./1w$')

matches = pattern.finditer(string)
for match in matches
   print (match)
```

But from the above code, I don't see any output

Comment: The regex should be `^(.).*\1$`. I'm not sure about the used functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if and only if you really want to use regex (for learning purpose):

```
import re
string = 'aba'
string2 = 'no match'
pattern = re.compile(r'^(.).*\1$')

if re.match(pattern, string):
  print('ok')
else:
  print('nok')
if re.match(pattern, string2):
  print('ok')
else:
  print('nok')
```

output:

```
ok
nok
```

Explanations:

```
^(.).*\1$
```

- `^` start of line anchor
- `(.)` match the first character of the line and store it in a group
- `.*` match any characters any time
- `\1` backreference to the first group, in this case the first character to impose that the first char and the last one are equal
- `$` end of line anchor

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/DaOPEl/1/

Otherwise the best approach is to simply use the comparison `string[0] == string[-1]`

```
string = 'aba'
if string[0] == string[-1]:
  print 'same'
```

output:

```
same
```

Comment: This does not work for single characters. For example, 'a' starts and ends with the same characters. This regex will only work for 2+ characters in a string.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you overengineer with an regex at all? One principle of programming should be keeping it simple like:

```
string[0] is string[-1]
```

Or is there a need for regex?

Comment: Thanks @Tobias, but I'd be parsing a whole lot of data by reading files in Python for which I believe Regex would be more suitable. 
Also String[0] = String[-1] work consider anything and not specifically limit itself to alphabets (meaning would only work for clean data). 

Hence specifically looking for regex implementation

Answer (score 2):

The above answer of @Tobias is perfect & simple but if you want solution using regex then try the below code.

Try this code !

**Code :**

```
import re
string = 'abbaaaa'
pattern = re.compile(r'^(.).*\1$')

matches = pattern.finditer(string)
for match in matches:
   print (match)
```

**Output :**

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='abbaaaa'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the regex you are trying to execute:

Code:

```
import re
string = 'aba'
pattern = re.compile(r'^(\w).(\1)$')

matches = pattern.finditer(string)
for match in matches:
   print (match.group(0))
```

Output:

```
aba
```

Comment: Thanks Omkar, it really worked.
I'm assuming we're just matching the first character with the 1st occurrence at the end of the string ? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @bzflag Yes. We have grouped the first character using () and then matched the first group with \1

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check with regex use below:

```
import re
string = 'aba is a cowa'
pat = r'^(.).*\1$'
re.findall(pat,string)
if re.findall(pat,string):
    print(string)
```

this will match first and last character of line or string if they match then it returns matching character in that case it will print string of line otherwise it will skip